# Dynamically create a message

Tags: python, odoo

I have a button on a new form. When this button clicked I need a show some information on new form using label /or other component/. How to do it in OpenERP 6? I don't have any idea. Please give me a hand. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easier way, but one way is to [build a wizard](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_10_wizard/index.html) that just displays your message.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to raise any kind of error message or you want to have confirmation ?

if you want to raise exception, then it's possible , check in the addons/account.py 
you'll find something that you are looking for.